# How to discover (standard) function names?

Tags: help, documentation, apropos

When programing emacs (or common) lisp, how to discover (standard) function names (using emacs and working offline)?

*Example:* Let's say you want to shift bits of an integer, but you don't now the name of the function, which can do this (hint: the name is `ash`, but you don't know, yet).
`apropos` isn't helping you, because it does not list `ash` when asking for `shift`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apropos help in Emacs is by no means limited to function `apropos`.

1. `M-x apropos documentation`.  It lets you match keywords or a regexp against doc strings. Very helpful when you don't know how the function might be named but you might be able to guess some words used in its doc.

   For example, `M-x apropos-documentation RET shift bit RET` shows you the names and doc for just the functions `lsh` and `ash`. Simple, effective.

   ```
   lsh
   Function: Return VALUE with its bits shifted left by COUNT.
   If COUNT is negative, shifting is actually to the right.
   In this case, zeros are shifted in on the left.

   (fn VALUE COUNT)

   ----------------
   ash
   Function: Return VALUE with its bits shifted left by COUNT.
   If COUNT is negative, shifting is actually to the right.
   In this case, the sign bit is duplicated.

   (fn VALUE COUNT)
   ```
2. There are also these other Apropos commands:

   ```
   apropos-command
   apropos-follow
   apropos-function 
   apropos-library
   apropos-local-value
   apropos-local-variable
   apropos-option
   apropos-value
   apropos-variable
   ```

   See also [**`apropos-fn+var.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/apropos-fn%2bvar.el).
3. The [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/) (`C-h r`), `i`, is your friend.  Likewise, the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/) (`C-h i`, choose Elisp).
4. [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) [apropos support](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos) -- including [documentation-apropos commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos#Documentation-AproposMulti-Commands), which provide the functionality of `apropos-documentation`, but which let you match against both the function name (e.g. parts of it) and the doc string.

In answer to your question in the comments, I don't really know how to find similar info for Common Lisp. Perhaps someone else will have a good answer about that.  But:

- You can certainly use `i` in the CL Info manual provided by Emacs.
- Googling "common lisp docstring" turned up [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5093513/729907) as the first hit. Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to do this for common lisp with slime and hyperspec installed? ;)